# PHP $_SESSION working in some browsers, not others

Tags: php, session, cross-browser

I have a webpage that uses PHP `$_SESSION` variables. It works fine on my computer using Google Chrome (version `44.0.2403.157` (64-bit)), but it doesn't work for other browsers or other versions of Chrome.

What can I do to fix this? I would prefer if I could keep using `$SESSION` variables so I don't have to recode all my webpages, but if I must, what is an alternative?

For context: I use the `$_SESSION` variables to store information such as the identity of who is "logged in" to my site and products in a user's "shopping cart".

Code: I start a session like this:

```
function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id';   // Set a custom session name
    $secure = false;
    // This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
    $httponly = true;
    // Forces sessions to only use cookies.
    if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
        header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
        exit();
    }
    // Gets current cookies params.
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
        $cookieParams["path"], 
        $cookieParams["domain"], 
        $secure,
        $httponly);
    // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_name($session_name);
    session_start();            // Start the PHP session 
    session_regenerate_id(true);    // regenerated the session, delete the old one. 
}
```

Like I said before, it works fine in certain browsers. Something is preventing it from working in others.

By "working", I mean the browser allows for the use of `$SESSION` variables. I do **not** mean the variables save across browsers.

When I check the cookies of the browser where it does not work, it says that it is storing cache, cookies, and local storage for my website.

Here a small example of my code. Here, when the login button is pressed, it checks the login credentials.

```
<?php
/**
* 
*
*/


                        include_once 'db-credentials.php';  //get database credentials 
                        $mydb2= logindb(); //login to database

                        sec_session_start(); //start session




//process form data                        
if(isset($_POST['btn-login'])) //if login button was pressed
{

 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $upass = $_POST['pwd'];
 $row = $mydb2->get_row($mydb2->prepare( 
        "select * from users WHERE email='$email'"), ARRAY_A
        );
 if($row['password']==$upass)
 {
  $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];
  $_SESSION['name'] = $row['username'];
  echo "<script>window.location = 'http://mywebsite.ca/order/'</script>";
 }
 else
 {
  ?>
        <script>alert('Invalid login. Please check your email and password and try again');</script>
        <?php
 }

}
```

Now, that code runs fine. With a correct username and password, the program gets into the inner `if` statement and will run the `echo "<script>window.location = 'http://mywebsite.ca/order/'</script>";` statement.

However, when it gets to `http://mywebsite.ca/order/`, it no longer has the session variables saved!

Comment: I'm not sure why you re-invent or re-write the `session_start()` function.

Comment: what is it good for?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois  I use a modified session_start() for security reasons.

As well, changing it to session_start() does not fix my problem. Still not working.

Comment: Why don't you set the session cookie params in the php.ini? That would mean you can scratch everything and just use `session_start(); session_regenerate_id(true);`

Comment: @Script47 No, that is not what I mean. What I mean is that the variables actually work. For example, if I do `$_SESSION["name"] = Mel` and then I do `echo $_SESSION["name"]` .... it should output "Mel".

Comment: @CharlotteDunois That does not fix my problem. I do not have a problem with that.

Comment: Check if you get a cookie at all. Use the browser's developer tools. They exist for something - not for decoration, if that would be your answer.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I just checked and it says it is storing cache, cookies, and local storage for my website, in the browser where it isn't working.

Comment: Does it send the cookies it gets when you refresh?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I'm not sure. Is that something I code into my program, or something I check my browser for?

Comment: @Mel : The code you have given is located in server and as it is php, it runs on server only. What is the relation between this code and browser. show the code which accessing this session variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Before, I was calling the `get_header()` function before I was calling the `session_start()` function. This worked fine on some browsers but not others.

I changed it so `session_start()` is my first statement.